# Existing Blazor Web Assembly Web APP Not Run in the MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

I already have existing Blazor web assembly Project up and running perfect.
Now my target is to run this same Web app into MAUI Blazor Hybrid App.
to Run this project I  follow the following project structure.

1- API client
2- WebApp Blazor Client project
3- MAUI app
4- Shared.core.UI
5- Shared.core.Services.

i have Two index.html file the first with WEBAPP and the second in the MAUI app.

i also add the webview.js script in the index.html of the MAUI project.

but when i run the emulator the app crash with no error.

Any suggestion please

i try to remove the javascript file from the index.html of the maui project.

Comment: We can not know your project only by the words so can you provide some codes? Besides, did you use the debug mode to test the project?

Comment: Yes i found this error.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.external.receiveMessage is not a function
    at blazor.webview.js:1:40417
    at Object.st [as start] (blazor.webview.js:1:40735)

Comment: This seems like an issue about JavaScript. You can check the question about [Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: myFunction is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904059/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-myfunction-is-not-a-function).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using BitPlatform Templates which allows you to have Blazor WASM, Server, Hybrid and Electron from one code base.

https://bitplatform.dev/todo-template/getting-started

Comment: I can not start my project from scratch I did a lot of work for blazor web assembly.